# i need find the instance of an attribute that the object is into an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i dont know how i find the intance Motorola in the array clientes that is in a swich into a for. the exercise is this: Name and identification of de first cliente in buy a Motorola celphone. Maybe i need a condition like an if or a while in case 2 but i dont know how to do it. Again, sorry for my english, thanks!!!

```
package principal1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import recursos.Cliente;

public class Principal1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int opc = 0;
        double ventasLG = 0.0;
        int ventasKyocera = 0;
        String nombre = "";
        Cliente clientes[] = new Cliente[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {

            clientes[i] = new Cliente(nombre);

            String marcaCelular = "";
            int celular = 0;

            System.out.println("Ingrese marca del celular:\n1.-Nokia\n2.-Motorola" + "\n3.-LG\n4.-Kyocera");
            celular = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            switch (celular) {
            case 1:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Nokia");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                int cedulaIdentidad = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                int precioCelular = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i] = new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                break;
            case 2:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Motorola");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i] = new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);

                break;
            case 3:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("LG");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i] = new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                // 2
                ventasLG++;
                break;
            case 4:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Kyocera");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if (precioCelular >= 300000) {
                    ventasKyocera++;
                }
                clientes[i] = new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opcion incorrecta");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i need print nombre and cedulaIdentidad of the first Cliente in buy a Motorola, so how i find that Cliente what her marcaCelular is Motorola and was the first instance and i need her name and cedulaIdentidad. i make a switch for each marcaCelular and create a class Cliente for instantiate the clientes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `boolean motorola = false`, and inside `case 2` put a

```
if(!motorola) {
    System.out.println("print first Motorola client ...");
    motorola = true;
}
```

Or after you have all clients:

Every time a Cliente buys a phone, his information is saved in clientes array. This is stored in chronological order so the first guy that bought a Motorola will be before the next guys who bought the same phone. Then you only have to iterate the clientes array and print the first Cliente that bought a Motorola.

```
for(int i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {
    if(clientes[i].getMarcaCelular().equals("Motorola")){
        System.out.println(
            clientes[i].getNombre() + " , " + 
            clientes[i].getCedulaIdentidad()
        );
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, try to write code in English as a convention. Im sure you do not want to read [Chinese typed code](https://github.com/Snailclimb/JavaGuide/blob/3d143d1f5b836c385f43d6482ce7616645459e02/%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E4%B8%8E%E7%AE%97%E6%B3%95/source%20code/securityAlgorithm/src/main/java/com/snailclimb/ks/securityAlgorithm/Base64Demo.java#L15).